# Sencha Touch models inheritance

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can I define a Sencha Touch model so that it inherits all fields from another, adding some of its own?

This is enough to inherit all fields from a model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Foo', {
    extend: 'MyApp.model.Bar' 
});
```

But how can I add the new fields?

Comment: Have you tried what happens when you inherit fields? If this doesn't work you could clone the fields-Array of base-class and extend the list in sub-class. But then 'instanceof' will not work.

Comment: Didn't try but I don't see any reasons why the fathers fields shouldn't be overridden by the child. How/when would you clone and extend? This is exactly what I'm asking :)

Comment: Please try it (add fields property to sub-class) and if it doesn't work we'll find a workaround (by cloning fields).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'Id',
        fields: [{
            name: 'Id'
        }, {
            name: 'firstName'
        }, {
            name: 'lastName'
        }],
        hasMany: [{
            model: 'MyApp.model.Car'
        }]
    }
});



Ext.define("MyApp.model.Car", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'Id',
        fields: [{
            name: 'Id'
        }, {
            name: 'model'
        }, {
            name: 'make'
        }, {
            name: 'year'
        }, {
            name: 'personId'
        }],
        belongsTo: [{
            model: 'MyApp.model.Person',
            associationKey: 'personId'
        }]
    }
});
```

Hope it will help you!!!

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted to achieve but it's an interesting suggestion. If nothing better comes out I'll probably accept this answer.